# NancyFx - this.Context.EnableOutputCache - Does the cache check include headers?

Tags: caching, nancy

I can't find any documentation for NancyFx's EnableOutputCache. There is a demo of using it [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Caching/MainModule.cs) at the nancy repository.

I would like to know if just the url is checked in the cache check or if headers (particularly the Authorization Header) is checked because I would only like to cache on a per user basis and the user is obtained from the token in the authorization header.

Comment: Its an extension method https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Caching/CachingExtensions/ContextExtensions.cs#L14